# Make JavaScript interval synchronize with actual time

Tags: javascript, time

I want to make the seconds synchronize with the real time (`new Date()`) seconds, so that it would work if the page was loaded mid second.

```
setInterval(() => {
    console.log("hey im not synchronized");
}, 1000);
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is that possible?

Yep, like this:

```
setTimeout(() => {
    setInterval(() => console.log("hey im synchronized"), 1000)
}, 1000 - new Date().getMilliseconds());
```

Comment: Note that this will be as close as can be at the beginning, but it can diverge if the interval runs for a long time. If you need to stay precise at all times, this kind of checks should be made regularly.

Comment: @blex is right. timeouts and intervals in JS may often lie up to dozens of ms. Also, if there is some CPU-demanding task to the point when there is no free windows for executing interval'ed tasks, then the desynchronisation will add up.

Answer (score 2):

For this particular purpose, what you want is a self-synchronizing timing loop.  The basic idea is *not* to use `setInterval()`, but rather to calculate each time how many milliseconds later you want the loop to fire next time, and use `setTimeout()` to wait until then.

Here's a basic example:

```js
function oncePerSecond(callback) {
    var timerFunc = function () {
        // get the current time rounded down to a whole second (with a 10% margin)
        var now = 1000 * Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000 + 0.1);
        // run the callback
        callback(now);
        // wait for the next whole second
        setTimeout(timerFunc, now + 1000 - Date.now());
    };
    timerFunc();
}

// create a demo timer
oncePerSecond(function (now) {
    document.getElementById('local').textContent = new Date(now).toString();
});

// add an artificial 0.5 second delay for the second timer
setTimeout(function () {
    oncePerSecond(function (now) {
        document.getElementById('utc').textContent = new Date(now).toUTCString();
    });
}, 500);
```

```html
<p>The local time is now: <span id="local">...</span></p>
<p>The UTC time is now: <span id="utc">...</span></p>
```

Note how, even though the two timers in the snippet above start half a second apart, they synchronize immediately after the first update.

The reason for the funny-looking `+ 0.1` fudge factor in `Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000 + 0.1)` is because there's no guarantee that the timer won't sometimes fire early, just a few milliseconds before the clock ticks over.  The 0.1 second offset ensures that we'll round the current time forward in such cases, but that we'll still normally round the time down on the first update (or after possible unexpected delays).

For even better results, you may want to combine this technique with [`requestAnimationFrame()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) so that your timers won't needlessly fire while the user is e.g. looking at another tab:

```js
function oncePerSecondAnim(callback) {
    var frameFunc = function () {
        // get the current time rounded down to a whole second (with a 10% margin)
        var now = 1000 * Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000 + 0.1);
        // run the callback
        callback(now);
        // wait for the next whole second
        setTimeout(timerFunc, now + 1000 - Date.now());
    }, timerFunc = function () {
        requestAnimationFrame(frameFunc);
    };
    timerFunc();
}

// create a demo timer
oncePerSecondAnim(function (now) {
    document.getElementById('local').textContent = new Date(now).toString();
});

// add an artificial 0.5 second delay for the second timer
setTimeout(function () {
    oncePerSecondAnim(function (now) {
        document.getElementById('utc').textContent = new Date(now).toUTCString();
    });
}, 500);
```

```html
<p>The local time is now: <span id="local">...</span></p>
<p>The UTC time is now: <span id="utc">...</span></p>
```